# excluding Jboss AS 7 modules

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x

I have an EAR file that contains many ejb jar files and runs on Jboss 7.1.1. I need one of these ejb jar files to use hibernate3 instead of the default hibernate 4 used by Jboss.

I've added it as a module and added a dependency in the manifest file of the specific jar. The question is, how can I exclude hibernate 4 from this specific project?

I know about jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but all the examples i saw where talking about a web project, is it possible to add it to an ejb jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add `<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="hibernate3-bundled" />` to your persistence.xml file. Assuming you're using [Hibernate 3.5](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-PackagingtheHibernate3.5orgreater3.xJPApersistenceproviderwithyourapplication) or greater.

Comment: ould this work with a hibernate.cfg.xml file ? I'm working with Hibernate 3.6.9 but still using old cfg.xml files ...